# react-three-fiber display multiple skinned meshes on canvas

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Hi coding wizards community. It's my first experience with react-tree-fiber. I have 3d skinned model which i have placed on canvas. Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-bones-5fo1x?file=/src/index.js). What I want to achieve is being able to place multiple character in the scene based on some event like a button press etc. So far, I could not find anything that could help me achieve my goal. [Here](https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber/issues/245) is something that could have helped but I am unable to incorporate it in my code. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

useLoader caches the data, so both instances are trying to run on the same model. that may work on geometries, but i don't think you can have two skinned meshes reference the same skeleton. not even sure if you can clone it, it looks like that's not possible in threejs.

so the solution is simple. just do it like you would in plain threejs. instead of useLoader load the gltf with the GLTFLoader. it executes two fetch requests, pulls and parses the model two times.

```
const [model, set] = useState()
useEffect(() => new GLTFLoader().load(url, set), [url])
return model ? <primitive object={model.scene} /> : null
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-bones-7zw1c?file=/src/Stacy.js

otherwise i would pose the question differently or make a new one. try to clone the object in a useMemo and find out why it doesn't work. it should, so that could be a bug in threejs.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure that the loader is the issue. The loaders work with static models but skinned meshes specifically seem to be the issue.  I have tried replicating this approach without success. Also the example code sandbox crashes so a working example can’t be verified